# PHP undefined offset 2

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have this code here. I am trying to loop through the array i have and replace all the hashes and dash signs in color_codes. It works but i am getting an error `undefined offset 2` on the str replace lines. it is also adding another array at the end called 'color_codes'.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($colours); $i++) {
    for ($ii = 0; $ii < count($colours[$ii]); $ii++) {
        $colours[$i][$ii]['color_codes'] = str_replace(',','-', $colours[$i][$ii]['color_codes']);
        $colours[$i][$ii]['color_codes'] = str_replace('#','', $colours[$i][$ii]['color_codes']);

    }
}
```

Original array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [item_color] => Black
                    [color_codes] => #000000,#000000
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [item_color] => Red
                    [color_codes] => #FF0033,
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [item_color] => White
                    [color_codes] => #FFFFFF,
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [item_color] => Black
                    [color_codes] => #0C0C0C,#0C0C0C,
                )

        )
)
```

Array created after foreach

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [item_color] => Black
                    [color_codes] => 000000-000000-
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [item_color] => Red
                    [color_codes] => FF0033-
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [color_codes] => 
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [item_color] => White
                    [color_codes] => FFFFFF-
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [item_color] => Black
                    [color_codes] => 0C0C0C-0C0C0C-
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [color_codes] => 
                )

        )
)
```

I dont know where the problem seems to be, it works apart from the `Undefined offset error`

Answer (score 5):

```
for ($ii = 0; $ii < count($colours[$ii]); $ii++) {
```

should be

```
for ($ii = 0; $ii < count($colours[$i]); $ii++) {
```

But you may use `foreach` in favor to `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it incorrectly, change your loop as below,

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($colours); $i++) {
     // Here it should be less than count of $colours[$i]
     for ($ii = 0; $ii < count($colours[$i]); $ii++) { 
        $colours[$i][$ii]['color_codes'] = str_replace(',','-', $colours[$i][$ii]['color_codes']);
        $colours[$i][$ii]['color_codes'] = str_replace('#','', $colours[$i][$ii]['color_codes']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Im so blind! Thanks for your help.

Comment: It happens. Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace $colours[$ii] in second for with $colours[$i]:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($colours); $i++) {
    for ($ii = 0; $ii < count($colours[$i]); $ii++) {
        $colours[$i][$ii]['color_codes'] = str_replace(',','-', $colours[$i][$ii]['color_codes']);
        $colours[$i][$ii]['color_codes'] = str_replace('#','', $colours[$i][$ii]['color_codes']);

    }
}
```

In order to loop through second level array you need to correctly get the size of that array.
As xdazz mentioned foreach loop would clarify things a lot. Also [str_replace](http://www.php.net/str_replace) takes arrays for search and replace. That means you can use single str_replace line per color:

```
foreach ($colours as &$level1) {
    foreach ($level1 as &$level2) {
        $level2['color_codes'] = str_replace(array(',', '#'), array('-', ''), $level2['color_codes']);
    }
}
```